# Call ajax on certain conditions

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I hope I can get answers pretty quick. :)

I have this field in a form:

```
$form['secret_code'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Enter 5 character secret code'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'event' => 'keyup',
    'callback' => 'mymodule_secret_code_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'mymodule-wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace',
  ),
);
```

Basically, I want ajax to be processed only when **secret_code** contains at least **5 characters**. I want ajax to be processed right after the **5th** character entered so events like `blur` or `change` is not suitable. After the 5th character, I need to check values from the database.

In the code above, ajax is called every time I entered a key. Let's say: "Drupal". When I entered "D", ajax gets called. Then, when I entered "r", ajax is called again, making the typing very slow.

I can do this easily with **javascript/jquery**. With jquery, I can still use the `keyup` event, continue processing ajax when the 5th character is entered. So the approach of javascript/jquery is faster.

How can I do this in Drupal way?